# Need a better rule for Firebase Realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> [Firebase] Client access to your Realtime Database '---------------'
> expired 7 day(s) ago
>
> You chose to start developing in Test Mode, which left your Realtime
> Database instance completely open to the Internet. Because this choice
> made your app vulnerable to attackers, your database security rules
> were configured to stop allowing requests after the first 30 days.
> Starting 7 day(s) ago, all client requests to your Realtime Database
> instance have been denied and will continue to be denied until
> security rules are updated. Analysis is run daily; if you've modified
> your rules in the last 24 hours those changes may not be accounted
> for.

I am still developing my app and this email shows up....can you please suggest a better rule..my app contains user log in and registration and reseting name, passowrd, email..

Comment: Throw us a bone here - what do you want the rule to do? What is a 'good' rule?

Answer (score 1):

If you want anyone to be able to read your database but only logged users to write, you can use this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

where $user_id comes from your user json. This variable doesnt need to be called $user_id. It can be any variable from your user json. ex:

```
"users" : 
    {
        "user_id":
        {
            "name":"John Doe",
            "email":"email@example.com",
        }
    }
```

If you prefer to have your database read only, you can use this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

You can read more in [Database Security Rules.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions)

Comment: can the first rule be used so users cant log in and regiter

Comment: line 4 unknown variable

Comment: These rules are only for the Database. Registration / login takes place in Auth and not in the Realtime Database. What it does is that it checks if a user is logs and then they are allowed to change anything.

Comment: I would suggest updating the answer as this `$user_id` is not defined and will not work as -is.

Comment: I know you're trying but the rules shown in this answer are not correct as is. You can't have $user_id represent something without specifying what that is - it's a wild card and has to represent a defined node. For example if the structure is `/users/some_uid/some_child` the rule would have to be `rules/users/$uid` *then* you can use $uid as wildcard within the rule. See [Security Rules: using $ wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments)