# What do do when Firebase asks to change the rules for Realtime Databse

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've been working with the realtime database for quite a while and it worked very well > I took a week rest from my app and now it gives me trouble retreiving database from firebase realtime database.

[image: The warning I got on the Firebase site]

I don't really know what to do at this stage I just know I think something needs to be changed in this section of the site:

[image: in this section of the site.]

Comment: I recommend searching for the error message, as I can't imagine this hasn't been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+will+start+denying+client+requests. Some basic answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66370575, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64862061, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64280489

Comment: Thank you very much!